# Exiting SICStus - Command Line

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel, sicstus-prolog

Is there any other way of exiting SICStus on Command Line without having to press `^C` plus `e` after (I can't always get to this "help menu" with `^C`).

The "real" question is if it exists a command like `:exit` or `!quit`, similar to other command line interpreters.

I am using SICStus 4.3.5 on OSX High Sierra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

`?- halt.`

or simply `Ctrl + d`.